# Why is my MD5 value printing with extra "f" characters?

Tags: c++, md5, stdstring

I have strange problem when using at() method of std::string. I'd like to calculate md5 hash for given string using this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmd5-rfc/files/
Hash is calculated correctly, but there is a problem with printing it human way. The output is:

```
af04084897ebbf299b04082d105ab724
ffffffaf040848ffffff97ffffffebffffffbf29ffffff9b04082d105affffffb724
```

Code is:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include<string>
  #include<iostream>

  extern "C" {
      #include "md5.h"
  }

  int main()
  {
      md5_state_t state;
      md5_byte_t digest[16];

      std::string callid("f83bc385-26da-df11-95d5-0800275903dd@pc-archdev");

      md5_init(&state);
      md5_append(&state, (const md5_byte_t*)callid.c_str(), callid.length());

      std::string callid_digest((const char*)digest, 16);

      for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
          printf("%02x", digest[i]);
      }

      printf("\n");

      for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
          const char c = callid_digest.at(i);
          printf("%02x", c);
      }

      printf("\n");
  }
```

Where do the "f" characters come from ?

Comment: pejotr, I bought the code over since it's considered better for questions to be as self-contained as possible. I also changed the title to make it more indicative of the problem. Hope you don't mind. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your byte values are being sign-extended.

That happens when you promote the (signed) char to a wider type and the top bit is set, because it tries to preserve the sign (which is why you're seeing the extra `f` characters only for values greater than `0x7f`). Using an `unsigned char` should fix the problem:

```
const unsigned char c = callid_digest.at(i); // may need to cast.
```

Comment: Or better, use `md5_byte_t` which is `unsigned char`.

Comment: or use std::cout so that the type is auto detected.